# Find the set of real numbers ($x$ not equal to zero) such that $2x + 1/x < 3$.

Tags: functions, quadratics

Pretty straightforward question, I just had a question for the conclusion.

I rearranged, and factored and have the quadratic:

$$2x + 1/x < 3$$

(multiply both sides by x and rearrange)

$$2x^x - 3x + 1 < 0$$

$$(2x-1)(x-1) < 0$$

so $x<1/2$ and $x<1$?

Something tells me I've made an error at the end.

Comment: When you write $2x^x + 3x + 1$, I think you mean $2x^2 - 3x + 1$.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of avoiding mistakes it's often easier to factor than to cancel: rather than multiplying through by $x$, you factor

$$ \frac{1}{x} (2x^2 - 3x + 1) < 0 $$
$$ \frac{(2x-1)(x-1)}{x} < 0 $$

and then use the usual methods to finish the problem. It sounds like you need a reminder on those too: the method I learned is to find the roots and poles:

- $2x-1 = 0 \implies x = 1/2$
- $x-1 = 0 \implies x = 1$
- $x = 0 \implies x = 0$

and then make a sign table

$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& x < 0 & 0 < x < 1/2 & 1/2 < x < 1 & 1 < x 
\\ \hline
\\ 2x-1 & - & - & + & +
\\\hline
\\ x-1 & - & - & - & +
\\\hline
\\ x & - & + & + & +
\end{array} $$

and then you can work out which regions have a product with the correct sign.

Comment: Better than my answer (+1).

Answer (score 2):

When working with inequalities that have unknown stuff in a denominator, it can be a good idea to multiply by the *square* of the denominator:

$$2x+{1\over x}\lt3$$
becomes
$$2x^3+x\lt3x^2$$

A key point is the inequality stays pointing in the same direction, because you've multiplied both sides by something that's guaranteed to be *positive* (if $x\not=0$).  Moving the $3x^2$ to the other side and factoring as usual gives

$$x(2x-1)(x-1)\lt0$$

Since the roots of the cubic are $0$, $1/2$, and $1$, by inspection, it's easy to see that the inequality is satisfied when $x\lt0$ and when $1/2\lt x\lt 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is when you multiply by $x$.  If $x$ is negative, this will *switch the inequality* from $< $ to $>$.

- If $x$ is positive, your analysis shows that $x$ must be between $1/2$ and $1$ (for the quadratic to be negative).
- If $x$ is negative, the same analysis shows that $x$ must be *outside* the interval between $1/2$ and $1$, because after switching the inequality you will get $2x^2 - 3x + 1 > 0$.

Thus the complete solution to your question is

> $$
> x < 0 \textbf{ or } \tfrac12 < x < 1.
> $$

Comment: For your second solution
- I'm getting x<1/2 and x<1 

-  Therefore x < 1

How are you getting the solution x > 1/2?

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce This isn't a quadratic equation.  Reread the question.  Also, you are wrong.

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce *Why* don't you think my solution is right?  Do you disagree with the answer I got (which is the correct answer, see Hurkyl's and Barry Cipra's answers)?  If you're going to multiply by $x$, you have to do casework on if $x < 0$ or $x > 0$.